# Availability using Access Database

Tags: vb.net, button

I am attempting to make a hotel booking system. However the availability has got me a bit confused. I have about 15 buttons which I am able to save the number to the database but when the form loads/ date changed. I need the button to stay red and be unclickable. For example if I had a room 11 booked from `3/06/17` to `5/06/17` then I'd need the button to remain red from the `3/06/17` to `4/06/17` since the room is able to still be booked on the `5/06/17` after cleaning. I hope this makes sense. Below is the code I am using to try to do this. The code does run however the button does not turn red.

I was thinking does my SQL statement need to be changed but I'm not too sure. I'm pretty new to coding so an explanation would be helpful. Thanks.

```
Private Sub ReadRecords()
            Dim btn As Button = Nothing
            Dim BookingFound As Boolean = False
            Using MyConn As New OleDbConnection
                MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
                MyConn.Open()
                Dim check As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [BookingInformation] WHERE [Date In] = '" & dtpDateIn.Value.Date & "' AND [Date Out] = '" & dtpDateOut.Value.Date & "'"
                Dim BookingExists As Boolean = False
                Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(check, MyConn)
                Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                    While reader.Read()
                        If reader(0) = 0 Then
                            BookingExists = False
                        Else
                            BookingExists = True
                        End If
                    End While
                End Using
                If BookingExists = True Then
                    Dim getData As String = "SELECT * FROM [BookingInformation] WHERE [Date Out] = '" & dtpDateOut.Text & "'"
                    Dim command2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(getData, MyConn)
                    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command2.ExecuteReader()
                        While reader.Read()
                            BookingFound = True
                            strDateIn = reader("Date In").ToString()
                            strDateOut = reader("DateOut").ToString
                            strRoomNumber = reader("Room Number").ToString
                        End While
                        If BookingFound = True Then
                            btn.BackColor = Color.Red
                        End If
                    End Using
                End If
                MyConn.Close()
            End Using
        End Sub

         Private Sub Room_Booking_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            ReadRecords()
        End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you need to use also a Room Number in your queries? I don't think you have to manage just one room

Comment: Make the button enable = false to disable.

Comment: This is a great chance to learn how to use the great debugger built into Visual Studio.  Set a breakpoint and watch what happens to variables as the code runs.  The first thing to do is to learn how to use SQL parameters - that has not been the right way to create SQL for several years.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your access database understand your input as date, access database is very sensitive to datatypes, for example if you write

```
 "SELECT * FROM [user_tb] WHERE user_id=1"
```

Your code will work fine if your user_id data type is autonumber. 
so try

```
 Dim getData As String = "SELECT * FROM [BookingInformation] WHERE [Date Out] = #" & dtpDateOut.Text & "#"
```

Instead of

```
 Dim getData As String = "SELECT * FROM [BookingInformation] WHERE [Date Out] = '" & dtpDateOut.Text & "'"
```

That is replace ' with #